# Perform Action when UIButton State changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I have a UIButton that performs an Action when it is touched down. 
I do this with

```
[inButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cardTouchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Now I want to perform another action when the button leaves this state. Any advices how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [another event](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) - UIControlEventTouchUpInside for example

```
[inButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cardTouchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Okay I asked the wrong question. I recognized that I want to perform a action when the button is highlighted and perform another action when he leaves the highlighted state... Another advice?

Sorry I think your answers is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` ?

You can find all UIControll Everts [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (See Constants)